# Distinct cascaded subsets of a given set

Tags: combinatorics

Let S be a set of n elements. The number of ways in which n distinct non-empty subsets $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ of S can be chosen such that $X_1\subseteq X_2...\subseteq X_n$, is...?

I think that all the subsets can be distinct iff there is one element in $X_1$, two elements in $X_2$ (including the one in $X_1$) and so on. So, for $X_1$ we have n choice, for $X_2$ we have n-1 choices and so on. Thus, total number of ways is $n!$. Please verify if the approach and answer is correct?

Comment: looks good to me :)

Comment: @Yorch Thank you